# C# example of using PhantomJS webdriver ExecutePhantomJS to filter out images

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs

I am looking to be able to selectively turn on and off certain images. I've come across the following article:

[PhantomJS how to skip download resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486377/how-can-i-control-phantomjs-to-skip-download-some-kind-of-resource)

I've also found this article which is very similar using python:

[Selenium driven by PhantomJS/Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099070/prevent-css-other-resource-download-in-phantomjs-selenium-driven-by-python)

I am presuming that I can do this via `webdriver.ExecutePhantomJS(string script, params object[] args)`.

What I don't know is if I need to create some page object first via the Selenium PageFactory and then call this function? How would I turn it off again. An example of how to do this would be very helpful.

Answer (score 5):

I was just looking for something similar...

This, for example, will ignore all urls ending with ".png":

```
using (var driver = new PhantomJSDriver())
{
    const string phantomScript = "var page=this;page.onResourceRequested = function(requestData, request) { var reg =  /\\.png/gi; var isPng = reg.test(requestData['url']); console.log(isPng,requestData['url']); if (isPng){console.log('Aborting: ' + requestData['url']);request.abort();}}";
    var script = driver.ExecutePhantomJS(phantomScript);
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com/");                
    driver.GetScreenshot().SaveAsFile("googlewithoutimage.png",ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

note that the 'page' object that you're looking for is 'this' in the ExecutePhantomJS scope, also note that I'm writing to the log to get a better understanding of what's happening.

This gives you the flexibility to turn on or off images selectively, as you required.

Comment: Do you know if one should be calling `Quit();` on the driver object?

Comment: From my experience you should actually use Quit, and not just dispose (as otherwise, for me, the window stays open).

What I usually do  is create a PhantomQuiter disposable wrapper class for the driver, that has a Driver property that returns the driver. and the wrapper quits in its dispose.

Comment: If anyone is trying out Selenium and PhantomJS for the first time like me then these are the NuGet packages to install http://i.imgur.com/8wc8QC4.png